# In Asp.net MVC How do i pass parameter in custom attribute dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I trying to pass value into custom attribute from view side in ASP MVC. My process flow will be like this -->

1. fill employee details
2. click on save button
3. Password window has to open
4. this password i want pass in custom attribute (Stuck Here)
5. Condition will check password is correct or not

Below is my Custom Attributes

```
public class LevelSecurityAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public string PageName {get;set;}
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string InvokeMethod { get; set; }

    public void LevelSecurity(string pagename,string invokemethod,string password)
    {
        this.PageName = pagename;
        this.Password = password;
    }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //My Condition logic
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        filterContext.Result=new  RedirectResult("~/"+PageName+"/"+InvokeMethod);
    }
}
```

Below is my Action Method

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[LevelSecurity(PageName = "DocumentType", InvokeMethod = "Index", Password = **Need pass Password from View side stuck here**)]
public ActionResult Create(EmployeeMaster Employee,string password)
{
    //Insert Employee Data if Password is Valid
    return View();
}
```

Please friends help me and if my concept is wrong please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Use the same `ActionExecutingContext` object to grab the posted value via the `ActionParameters` property. You don't have to specify the password parameter again in the Create method signature, unless you need it there too. If you don't want to hardcode the parameter key, promote it to a property in the action filter class, like you did with `PageName` and `InvokeMethod`. Btw, there are well established ways to do *authentication* and *authorization* with ASP .Net, from `FormsAuthentication` to `ASP .Net Identity`.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{

    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    var password = filterContext.ActionParameters.ContainsKey("password") 
                ? filterContext.ActionParameters["password"] : null;
    ....

}
```

Comment: In other words, you *can't* pass in the password, but you can access the request context and get the value from there.

Comment: Yes... anyway I don't think OP will have any success with this scenario either. Should a client pass his password with every request??